# NullPointerException catched multiple times on RecyclerView

Tags: android, geolocation, settings

Hello everybody hope you're fine, my problem is that I get a NullpointerException catched everytime I try to detect if location is disabled, if so the user will be redirected to Settings to enable gps and because I have a recycler view of places that have distance between my location and their location the settings will be displayed many times if location is disabled (as many as number of places)
Here is the code:

```
 public double Calculdistance(Pharmacien ph) {
    float[] result = new float[10];
    ml = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try{
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return 0;
    }
    Location location = ml.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    onLocationChanged(location);

    Location.distanceBetween(latitude,longtitude,ph.getPosition().getLatitude(),ph.getPosition().getLongitude(),result);}
    catch (NullPointerException e){
       Toast.makeText(context, "GPS désactivée activer le svp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intentRedirectionGPSSettings = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        intentRedirectionGPSSettings.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

        context.startActivity(intentRedirectionGPSSettings);

    }


    return Math.round(result[0]);

}
```

Comment: What class `Calculdistance` belongs to?

NullpointerException means that you have null object and try to use its fields or methods. Please make a breakpoint with your debugger on the line where you got NPE and find which object is null and write here. As far as I understood the line is `if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission...`  so it might be `context`

Comment: Kindly post error logs so that we know what is the issue

Comment: My problem is not the null pointer exception my problem is that I want to catch it once instead of number of recycler view  items